# How do I correctly load data into a Picker with an ArrayDataModel? (Blackberry OS 10 Cascades)

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am working with Blackberry 10 Cascades and I am trying to load data into a picker using an `ArrayDataModel`. All of the documentation online I have read thusfar have given me examples to use with `XMLDataSource`, however since my data is JSON and coming from a live feed I would rather not have to take the performance hit of serializing it into XML to load into the `XMLDataSource` (which seems to be pretty temperamental from my cursory investigations).

I have some code that is giving me partial functionality (correct number of rows and columns), however when attempting to access the `pickerItemData` property, the result is always undefined.

The following code shows the partial functionality, it is adapted from [http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb_*cascades*_picker.html](http://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/cascades/bb__cascades__picker.html)

There is some debug output from the Console which reads

```
Picker: incorrect model, wrong columns number:  0
```

Unfortunately this doesn't make any sense to me, as the `Picker` is rendering the correct number of columns. There also does not appear to be any documentation on the error message.

```js
import bb.cascades 1.2

Page {
    Container {
        leftPadding: 24.0
        rightPadding: 24.0
        topPadding: 12.0
        bottomPadding: 12.0
        controls: [
            Picker {
                id: picker
                title: "Picker title"
                expanded: true
                rootIndexPath: []
                dataModel: ArrayDataModel {
                    id: dataModel
                }

                pickerItemComponents: [
                    PickerItemComponent {
                        type: "item1"

                        content: Container {
                            background: Color.create(pickerItemData.background)
                        }
                    },
                    PickerItemComponent {
                        type: "item2"

                        content: Container {
                            Label {
                                text: pickerItemData.text
                                textStyle.color: Color.create(pickerItemData.color)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]

                onCreationCompleted: {
                    dataModel.append([
                            {
                                "item1": [ {
                                        "background": "#ff0000ff"
                                    }, {
                                        "background": "#ff00ff00"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "background": "#ffff0000"
                                    }, {
                                        "background": "#ff00ffff"
                                    } ]
                            },
                            {
                                "item2": [
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 1",
                                        "color": "#ff888888"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 2",
                                        "color": "#ff0000ff"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 3",
                                        "color": "#ff00ff00"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 4",
                                        "color": "#ff00ffff"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 5",
                                        "color": "#ffff0000"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 6",
                                        "color": "#ffff00ff"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 7",
                                        "color": "#ffffff00"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "text": "Item 8",
                                        "color": "#ffffffff"
                                    } ]
                            } ]);
                }

                onSelectedValueChanged: {
                    var index0 = picker.selectedIndex(0);
                    var index1 = picker.selectedIndex(1);
                    console.log("Selection: " + index0 + ", " + index1);
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The structure of the data provided via JSON is identical to the structure of the data provided by the `XMLDataSource`. Any help or insight into this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The debug you see telling you that there's no column comes from the fact that you create your model in the ``onCreationCompleted`` slot. The picker will first be initialized with an empty model as you fill it later.